# GoogleEarth realtime update with python

Tags: python, flask, real-time, kml, google-earth

I am trying to show a object moving in google earth in realtime.

I have found several webpages that convince me this is somewhat do-able. I am running into some issue though.

I have gotten a network link to a kml file that I update with new lat/lon periodically but since one program is writing to that file (my python code) and another needs to read from it (google earth) there is bottleneck and it causes nasty lag.

I have also seen that you can use a python script as the network link file, given it is on a server. Which I assume means each time google earth refreshes it calls that python script which returns a kml string.

I implemented that theory using flask but I am not getting any results. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Code below:

My network link kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Network Links</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <open>0</open>
    <description>Network link example 1</description>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>Aircraft 1</name>
      <visibility>0</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Test description</description>
      <refreshVisibility>0</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>127.0.0.1:5000/aircraft.kml</href>
          <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
          <refreshInterval>0.05</refreshInterval>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
from GoogleEarthDraw import kml_updater

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/aircraft.kml')
def send_py_app():
    print("Returning py file")
    return kml_updater.to_print_output()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Python KML producer (kml_updater.py):

```
def get_kml_text(latitude, longitude, altitude):
    return \
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Aircraft 1</name>
    <description>Show flight of aircraft 1</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>{},{},{}</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
'''.format(longitude, latitude, altitude)


def to_print_output():
    # Create the lat/lon/alt
    lat = 41.98583333
    lon = -91.57055556
    alt = 0

    return get_kml_text(lat, lon, alt)
```